# What could this tube sticking out of the roof be ? It was directly over the old ac system

Tags: hvac, roof, vent

We moved into this mobile home with a very old ac unit and we had a new one installed. The people who installed the new one said there was a hole and they weren’t sure what it lead to so they just covered it up without question and they didn’t tell us if they knew what it was but it’s directly over where the old ac unit used to be. On the roof side of things there is this tube thing that is coming out of it right where that hole used to be. Now I’m trying to figure out what it was and what I should do about it. Thank you for the help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know what it was, but if the other end of it has been covered up and it's obviously no longer in use I would remove it and repair the roof.

Comment: That was a pretty sloppy job of installing the vent pipe in the first place and of patching the ceiling after the fact. I'd agree that since it appears to no longer be in use, you would be best served by removing it and patching the roof. That looks ripe for a leak.

Answer (score 0):

On the roof likely a vent for an attic fan or waste watter

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a heater/furnace vent. My attic AC is in combination with a furnace, pretty typical. Likely your original AC had a furnace.